# Remove stale/obsolete geometry columns from the geometry_columns table

Tags: postgis, geometry, administration

I understand that the function `Populate_Geometry_Columns()` inserts records in the `geometry_columns` table for geometry columns that are not yet listed there. However, an invocation of `Probe_Geometry_Columns()` reports:

```
select probe_geometry_columns();
              probe_geometry_columns               
---------------------------------------------------
 probed:1086 inserted:0 conflicts:1086 stale:53612
(1 row)
```

This is after a call to `Populate_Geometry_Columns()`. Is there an easy/documented way how to get rid of the conflicts and the stale entries?

This has been posted a while ago to dba.sx with no replies: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/14975/6934.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a function from within postgis to do what you're talking about. But you have three options that I see:

First, just truncate geometry_columns, then re-run `SELECT probe_geometry_columns()`. If that's too frightening, then:

Second, you can do this with a bit of introspection. This should work:

```
DELETE FROM geometry_columns g
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 from information_schema.columns as c
     JOIN geometry_columns g ON 
       (c.table_schema=g.f_table_schema
        AND c.table_name = g.f_table_name 
        AND c.column_name = g.f_geometry_column)
    )
```

As always, you should test that before actually doing anything, but `probe_geometry_columns()` should fix it if you screw it up too badly. I didn't test that code because I've already done:

Third, you can upgrade to PostGIS 2.x, where geometry_columns has become a view, and is thus always current – `probe_geometry_columns()` no longer exists, nor is it needed.

Comment: Good it's finally fixed in 2.0, and the workaround should do until then.